# Django templates {% block content %} can contain only two form fields?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, jinja2

The question is: Can we send in the form into the template with more than 2 fields(I'm sure it should be possible). Please, advice what might be the issue:

I've created the form with 3 fields:

```
class Email(forms.Form):
    owner = forms.ChoiceField(choices=['Tyler', 'Aleks'])
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=150, label='Name the stuff')
    file = forms.FilePathField(path=path, label='Enter the path')
```

Afterward, operated it in view, where I'm sending form object to the template:

```
def mail_distribution(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Email(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            render(request, 'general/email.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = Email()
    return render(request, 'general/email.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the template itself:

```
{% extends 'general/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
     <form class="form-vertical" action="mail_distrib" role="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inherit">
                <center>
                    {{form.title}}
                </center>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inherit">
                <center>
                    {{form.owner}}
                </center>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inherit">
                <center>
                    {{form.file}}
                </center>
            </div>
          <center><input type="submit" value="OK"></center>
     </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Afterwards I get the error:

*Error during template rendering

In template E:\Tyler\Projects\Web_dev\dj_api\Scripts\distribution\general\templates\general\email.html, error at line 13
too many values to unpack (expected 2)

line13 - 13 {{form.owner}}*

Comment: Are you sure you are posting all your code? Looks like you are trying to send an email, and something goes wrong there. Why are you rendering a form when the form is valid?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback. The number of form fields is not the problem here.

Comment: @Alasdair edited the question, thank you!

Comment: @het.oosten I will write the logic of email sending afterwards, I need to set up the fields at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `choices` attribute in owner fields like this

```
owner = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('Tyler','Tyler'), ('Aleks', 'Aleks')])
```